# Building Boost.Coroutines2 examples

Tags: c++, boost, boost-coroutine, boost-coroutine2

I'm trying to build the Boost 1.59 coroutine and coroutine2 examples.
I built boost with b2 (complete build)  and am using CMake to generate a VC2015 project to build the samples.

All the coroutine samples build and run just fine, but I get linking errors with the *coroutine2* samples.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file is straightforward, just find boost, include the headers and link to the boost libs:

```
project (coroutines-samples)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)


find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})


add_executable(chaining.cpp         /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/chaining.cpp)
add_executable(echo.cpp             /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/echo.cpp)
add_executable(exception.cpp        /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/exception.cpp)
add_executable(fibonacci.cpp        /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/fibonacci.cpp)
add_executable(layout.cpp           /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/layout.cpp)
add_executable(parallel.cpp         /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/parallel.cpp)
add_executable(power.cpp            /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/power.cpp)
add_executable(same_fringe.cpp      /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/same_fringe.cpp)
add_executable(segmented_stack.cpp  /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/segmented_stack.cpp)
add_executable(simple.cpp           /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/simple.cpp)
add_executable(unwind.cpp           /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/asymmetric/unwind.cpp)
add_executable(dice_game.cpp        /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/symmetric/dice_game.cpp)
add_executable(merge_arrays.cpp     /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/symmetric/merge_arrays.cpp)
add_executable(segmented_stack1.cpp /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/symmetric/segmented_stack.cpp)
add_executable(simple1.cpp          /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/symmetric/simple.cpp)
add_executable(unwind1.cpp          /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp03/symmetric/unwind.cpp)
add_executable(await_emu.cpp        /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp11/asymmetric/await_emu.cpp)
add_executable(fibonacci11.cpp      /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp11/asymmetric/fibonacci.cpp)
add_executable(iterator_range.cpp   /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp11/asymmetric/iterator_range.cpp)
add_executable(layout11.cpp         /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp11/asymmetric/layout.cpp)
add_executable(same_fringe11.cpp    /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp11/asymmetric/same_fringe.cpp)
add_executable(merge_arrays1.cpp    /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp11/symmetric/merge_arrays.cpp)
add_executable(simple2.cpp          /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine/example/cpp11/symmetric/simple.cpp)


# coroutines2
add_executable(coro2_fibonacci     /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine2/example/fibonacci.cpp)
add_executable(coro2_layout        /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine2/example/layout.cpp)
add_executable(coro2_parser        /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine2/example/parser.cpp)
add_executable(coro2_same_fringe   /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine2/example/same_fringe.cpp)
add_executable(coro2_segmented     /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine2/example/segmented.cpp)
add_executable(coro2_simple        /some/path/boost_1_59_0/libs/coroutine2/example/simple.cpp)


target_link_libraries(chaining.cpp        ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(echo.cpp            ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(exception.cpp       ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(fibonacci.cpp       ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(layout.cpp          ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(parallel.cpp        ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(power.cpp           ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(same_fringe.cpp     ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(segmented_stack.cpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(simple.cpp          ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(unwind.cpp          ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(dice_game.cpp       ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(merge_arrays.cpp    ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(segmented_stack1.cpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(simple1.cpp         ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(unwind1.cpp         ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(await_emu.cpp       ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(fibonacci11.cpp     ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(iterator_range.cpp  ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(layout11.cpp        ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(same_fringe11.cpp   ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(merge_arrays1.cpp   ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(simple2.cpp         ${Boost_LIBRARIES})


target_link_libraries(coro2_fibonacci     ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(coro2_layout        ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(coro2_parser        ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(coro2_same_fringe   ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(coro2_segmented     ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(coro2_simple        ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The linked does not seem to be able to find boost::system::system_category.
This is my error log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: coro2_fibonacci, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

2>------ Build started: Project: coro2_layout, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

3>------ Build started: Project: coro2_parser, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

4>------ Build started: Project: coro2_same_fringe, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

5>------ Build started: Project: coro2_segmented, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

6>------ Build started: Project: coro2_simple, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

1>libboost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib(stack_traits.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int,char const *)" (??0thread_exception@boost@@QEAA@HPEBD@Z)

1>\some\path\Coroutines\build\vs2015.x64\Debug\coro2_fibonacci.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

4>libboost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib(stack_traits.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int,char const *)" (??0thread_exception@boost@@QEAA@HPEBD@Z)

4>\some\path\Coroutines\build\vs2015.x64\Debug\coro2_same_fringe.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

6>libboost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib(stack_traits.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int,char const *)" (??0thread_exception@boost@@QEAA@HPEBD@Z)

2>libboost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib(stack_traits.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int,char const *)" (??0thread_exception@boost@@QEAA@HPEBD@Z)

3>libboost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib(stack_traits.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int,char const *)" (??0thread_exception@boost@@QEAA@HPEBD@Z)

5>libboost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib(stack_traits.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int,char const *)" (??0thread_exception@boost@@QEAA@HPEBD@Z)

6>\some\path\Coroutines\build\vs2015.x64\Debug\coro2_simple.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

2>\some\path\Coroutines\build\vs2015.x64\Debug\coro2_layout.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

3>\some\path\Coroutines\build\vs2015.x64\Debug\coro2_parser.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

5>\some\path\Coroutines\build\vs2015.x64\Debug\coro2_segmented.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

7>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

7>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 6 failed, 25 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add MESSAGE(STATUS "!!!!! BOOST LIBS LIST: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}") last line in your CMakeLists.txt file and show list libraries. Visual Studio MSVC linker not found "boost_system" library

Comment: Try see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html
For msvc i'm using

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON) and
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

Compare b2 build options and cmake flags